# When is the best time to update the Unity Camera?

Tags: unity-game-engine

Sorry to ask such as simple question, but my friend and I were discussing when is the best time to move the camera in a Unity3d game.
Basically discussing whether we should move it on an `Update`, `FixedUpdate`, or `LateUpdate`.

I believe `LateUpdate` would be the best time to move the camera to ensure that all other calculations are done first. But he says you should do it during update and just set it to be the last thing that updates.

Can I get some feedback on either of these and why one may be better than the other?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From the [Unity docs](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.LateUpdate.html):

> LateUpdate is called after all Update functions have been called. This is useful to order script execution. For example a follow camera should always be implemented in LateUpdate because it tracks objects that might have moved inside Update.

This makes it sound like semantically there is no difference between `LateUpdate()` and making the camera update be the last statement in `Update()`. However, using `LastUpdate()` emphasizes that there is special significance to having the camera be updated at the end of the frame. This makes it less likely that someone in the future might accidentally add code later that would get executed after the camera update.

Comment: That makes sense to me. I know you can set the execution order so the things that need to run before the camera do. But I felt that why do that when you can just use the LateUpdate and call it good.

Answer (score 0):

How can you tell which one of the `Update()` functions is the last one called? Say you have multiple scripts, in which they all have an  `Update()` function. You put the camera movement code at the end of the `Update()` in your CameraController script. But you don't know if the `Update()` in CameraController script is the last one called among all the `Update()` in those scripts, and you are supposed to not rely on the execution order of `Update()`, which is stated in Unity Documentation.

`LateUpdate()` is called after all the `Update()` are called. Therefore, It is sure that your camera movement code will be executed in the last if you put them in `LateUpdate()`